# Background color in OSX Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, dashboard

I really like the dashboard background color on Snow Leopard, where it reduces the brightness of the monitors.

My monitors are too bright at night time, so I'd like to reduce the brightness?

How can I "use" the dashboard background color manually? or is there a program for this?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reduce the brightness using SystemPreferences->Displays because I am not using Apple's monitor.
I am using Logitech Wave Desktop, there is an option in Logitech Control Center to reduce/increase brightness, but sadly it does not work for me.

Lucky I found Shades, http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/23370/shades, which enable me to reduce/increase brightness using keyboard shortcut.

Also, using Universal Access (System Preferences->Keyboard->Universal Access), I can reverse black and white! Very cool.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the brightness of your display in System Preferences->Displays, or by using the keyboard shortcut if you have the right keyboard.